How can I create a data based preview for an audio file with QuickLookUI?
I'm trying to make a macOS quick look extension for a custom audio file format, to create a preview that will display in Finder. The idea is to convert the file to some audio file type that quick look knows how to deal with and provide that data in my QLPreviewReply, but quick look does not seem to accept any audio data in the reply.
So I'm experimenting with substituting different types of data in the QLPreviewReply to see if this can work. First I'll try text:
class PreviewProvider: QLPreviewProvider, QLPreviewingController {

    func providePreview(for request: QLFilePreviewRequest) async throws -> QLPreviewReply {        
    
        let contentType = UTType.plainText
        
        let reply = QLPreviewReply.init(dataOfContentType: contentType, contentSize: CGSize.init(width: 800, height: 800)) { (replyToUpdate : QLPreviewReply) in

            let data = Data("Hello world".utf8)
            replyToUpdate.stringEncoding = .utf8
            return data
        }
            
        return reply
    }
}

This works. When I press the space bar with my audio file highlighted, Quick Look displays "Hello world" in an 800x800 window. Now, a picture:
class PreviewProvider: QLPreviewProvider, QLPreviewingController {

    func providePreview(for request: QLFilePreviewRequest) async throws -> QLPreviewReply {        
        
        let contentType = UTType.png
        
        let reply = QLPreviewReply.init(dataOfContentType: contentType, contentSize: CGSize.init(width: 800, height: 800)) { (replyToUpdate : QLPreviewReply) in

            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "picture", ofType: "png")
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            return data
        }
        
        return reply
    }
}

This works too. I can display any picture bundled with my app.
But when I substitute an mp3 or wav, nothing happens. It just shows the default pop up window for an unsupported file. I have no errors, but I have verified that the path is correct, and data stores the data. It makes it all the way to the reply, Quick Look just decides to do nothing with it. Audio seems to be unsupported, even though Quick Look can preview common audio file types natively.
For reference, the documentation seemed to me to suggest that you can return any natively supported preview format, but there is little clarity on this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickLookUI. I have already gone the view controller route, but have run into strict limitations there as well.
So how can I get Quick Look to play audio in a data based preview? Is audio completely unsupported by this framework?
